# Pass a parameter from mvc webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is my code for MVC WebGrid

> @  var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage:
>   5, canSort: true);

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
       grid.Column(header: "#",
       format: item => item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1 + Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(grid.TotalRowCount / grid.PageCount) / grid.RowsPerPage) * grid.RowsPerPage * grid.PageIndex),
       //format: item => item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1),
       grid.Column(header: "Full Name", columnName: "full_name",canSort:false),
       grid.Column(header: "User Name", columnName: "user_name", canSort: false),
       grid.Column(header: "Password", columnName: "password", canSort: false),
       grid.Column(header: "User Email", columnName: "user_email", canSort: false),
       grid.Column(header: "Role", columnName: "role"),

       grid.Column(header: "",format:(item) =>
       {
           var link = Html.ActionLink("Add New", "AddNew", "Admin", new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-vs" });
           return link;

       }),
       grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) =>
       {
           //var link = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "", "", new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-primary", onclick = "Modalshow()" });
           var link = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Admin", new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-primary" });
           return link;

       }),
       grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) =>
       {
           var link = Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Admin", new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" });
           return link;

       }),
       grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) =>
       {
           var link = Html.ActionLink("Details", "Select", "Admin", new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-success " });
           return link;

       })

       )
        , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "table table-hover text-center" },
        nextText: "Go Next",
        previousText: "Go Back",
        footerStyle: ""
        )
```

In the below section

```
grid.Column(header: "",format:(item) =>
       {
           var link = Html.ActionLink("Add New", "AddNew", "Admin", new { id = item.id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-vs" });
           return link;
```

How can I pass user_email as a parameter in place of item.id ?
           }),

Answer (score 0):

You can add another parameter along with id

Try below code

```
 var link = Html.ActionLink("Add New", "AddNew", "Admin", new { id = item.id, user_email = "UserEmail" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-vs" });
```

Thanks

Comment: No , its null . From where you think it will set some value in UserEmail ??

Comment: the value you will have to pass

Comment: From where you expecting to get a value ? it has to be email id from same row . any suggestion to fetch that ?

Comment: Your WebGrid is being bound to "Model" therefore "item.id" is referring to a property on your model called "id". If you want to do as suggested here, you will need a property on your model called UserEmail. Then you can say user_email = item.UserEmail